# How to overload a linux command

Tags: linux, windows, git, terminal, command-line

Every time the user types `git commit -a`,
**I want to** run it in my own script,
Then run original command `git commit..` and have it run as it would have normally.

Comment: If this were possible, it would be a major security risk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use ".git/hooks" to install a "pre-commit" hook, perhaps:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

This is normally how you would do this. Of course, it would help if you explained exactly WHAT you want the "overload" to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your "hook" is not limited to only `git` but you need to make it work with any executable, you can use `alias`

```
alias git='myhackyscript.sh'
```

then `myhackyscript.sh` may looks like

```
#!/bin/bash

# save params
params=("$@")

# do what i want to do
do_something

# launch git 
git "${params[@]}"
```

`myhackyscript.sh` must be stored in a `$PATH` folder like `/usr/bin/`

Comment: how does it re-attach to the "real" git command?

Comment: Look at the last line. It will call git with his parameters taken from the shell command

Comment: it will call the original git, or it will call the new alias?

Comment: It will call the original git. You won't fall in a recursion.

Comment: Aliases don't expand into a non-interactive shell. Try yourself

Comment: @grawity thank you for editing my code, but it worked also without your updates.

Comment: @DavideBerra: For some definitions of "worked". As the edit description says, the original version would have mangled arguments that had spaces in them (e.g. `git commit -m "Fix hacky script"` would have been mangled into `git commit -m Fix hacky script`, which does a *completely different thing*).

Answer (score 0):

If you create a script `ls` in a location such as `~/bin` which is located on the `path` before `/bin/ls` your script will be executed instead.

```bsh
user@wopr /home/user/bin/: $ cat ls
#!/bin/bash

echo "Security Breached!"

# Run original command
/bin/ls "$@"
```

---

Now when listing files the message `Security Breached!` is always displayed.

```
user@wopr /home/user/bin/: $ ls
Security Breached!
ls file.sh file myscript.sh

user@wopr /home/user/bin/: $ which ls
/home/user/bin/ls
```

You should be aware of the directories on your `path` and who can write to those directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a shell function that invokes a custom script which then passes things on to the original git command:

```
git() {
  case $1 in
    commit)
      echo "WUFF"
      ;;
  esac
  \git "$@"
}
```

Putting this function into one of your shell's RC files (e.g. `~/.profile` or `/etc/profile` in the case of sh/bash/ksh shells) will make this available after the next login. Of course, you can get much more elaboare than this. Also, you might want to take a look at the [`git-sh-setup(1)`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-sh-setup.html) and [`git-rev-parse(1)`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) man-pages, in particular the section about `parseopt`.

Comment: You can `source ~/.profile` to update the current shell with the new function.,

Comment: Sure, and on Mac it's actually enough to just open a new terminal/tab. But the logout/login method is the bullet proof way ;-)

Comment: That's because each new terminal/tab invokes a new shell so all relevant config files such as `~/.bashrc` will be read. `source ~/.bashrc` will be *bulletproof* for updating the current shell with the changes.